# Django deployment with mod_wsgi on wamp 3.0.6

Tags: mod-wsgi, python-3.6

I  followed mod-wsgi document and installed mod-wsgi  using pip install command .It had been installed successfully.

I followed the command as suggested **mod_wsgi-express module-config** *mod_wsgi-express start-server* does not work in windows
and got the output:

Output :

```
LoadFile "c:/users/user/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/user/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi
.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/user"
```

Now I am not able to find how does it work with wamp as some one has suggested that mod_wsgi.so needs to be copied in apache folder to get it functional .

Wamp Version:3.0.6
    Apache :2.4.23
    Python : 3.6.
    Thanks in Advance

Post Changes in httpd.conf:

```
<Directory ${INSTALL_DIR}/www/wsgi-scripts>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    DocumentRoot ${INSTALL_DIR}/www

    <Directory ${INSTALL_DIR}/www>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/user/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp {$INSTALL_DIR}/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory ${INSTALL_DIR}/www/wsgi-scripts>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to copy the output from running `mod_wsgi-express module-config` and add it to the Apache configuration file. Then restart Apache to make sure it restarts okay.

Once that works, then configure Apache for your specific WSGI application, although better to start with a hello world WSGI application.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html

Comment: I copied it inside http.conf file and run the script  
 http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html following the link wamp server restarted correctly.. but www.example.com/myapp is not running  ...

Comment: What you mean by 'run the script'? What additional changes did you make to the Apache configuration file after adding the output of ``mod_wsgi-express module-config``? You should have added ``WSGIScriptAlias`` directive and other bits. Supply what you added.

Comment: Following are the changes i made in httpd.conf is shown in edited question in Post Changes in httpd.conf  section

Comment: Apache wouldn't even start if that is what you have. The ``LoadModule`` line can't be inside of the ``VirtualHost``. You also didn't include the ``LoadFile`` and ``WSGIPythonHome`` directives that ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` output. Further, you have typo in ``{$INSTALL_DIR}``. Plus that ``${INSTALL_DIR}`` isn't even going to work unless that is set as an environment variable. Fix that and then properly explain what you mean when you say it doesn't work. What errors? Where do you see the errors?

Comment: So please suggest where should i place loadmodule,Loadfile and WSGIPythonHome .....Should it be outside VirtualHost and it is outside what should be tags...I am newbie in python so any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: Since you likely only have the one site, you don't even need to put stuff in a ``VirtualHost``. So remove ``<VirtualHost *:80>`` and ``</VirtualHost>``. The ``LoadFile``, ``LoadModule`` and ``WSGIPythonHome`` must be in the order shown. They must be before you use ``WSGIScriptAlias``. I don't understand what you mean 'outside what should be tags'.

Comment: Thanks Graham Dumpleton a lot your suggestion i have read on Google group worked for me finally Mod_wsgi not giving expected result ....Thanks a lot ..<VirtualHost *:80>
 
 ServerName localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias /tester C:/projects/www/wsgi_scripts/test.wsgi 
    <Directory C:/projects/www/wsgi_scripts>
  Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

Comment: One more query how to use this in daemon mode i have read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html in this document but WSGIDaemonProcess  gives invalid command error when i used it before WSGIScriptAlias

Comment: You can't use daemon mode on Windows.